# How to refresh coordinates of mousemove when container dimensions change?

Tags: jquery, mousemove

I have a `figure` with child `img`. The image is large and shows a UX flow. I have set up an interaction where clicking the image will scale it up within the `figure`, and using `mousemove` with `transform-origin` to pan around and view the entire image and that works great. I am now making the presentation more immersive by expanding that `figure` fullscreen upon click, which also works, but the problem is that the coordinates for `mousemove` have obviously changed and the instant you pan/move the cursor, the image jumps/shifts as the coordinates update to the new context (the `figure` at its changed dimensions).

Code and Fiddle link are below.

**Recent Attempts**

I have tried dynamically inserting a new container for the image upon click so that would be the context of the coordinates but `mousemove` no longer worked.

I also tried targeting the `.zoomed` state of the `figure` for `mousemove` and that also prevented `mousemove` from working.

**HTML**

```
<div class="gallery-item-wrap">
  <figure class="zoom">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1040/1800/1000">
  </figure>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gallery-item-wrap {
  width: 70vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}

figure img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

figure.zoomed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure.zoomed img {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

**jQUERY**

```
$('.zoom').click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('zoomed');
});

$('.zoom')
.on('mousemove', function(e){
  $(this).children('.zoom img').css({'transform-origin': ((e.pageX - $(this).offset().left) / $(this).width()) * 100 + '% ' + ((e.pageY - $(this).offset().top) / $(this).height()) * 100 +'%'});
})
```

**JSFIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/iraishere/w1pe7tjm/19/

How can I recontextualize the coordinates when the image container's dimensions change?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Before the user clicks on that image, nothing happening (the `transition-origin` does changed but the is no visual impact). When the user clicks on the image, it getting bigger (`scale`) and it follows the mouse. So what's the problem?

Comment: As I described, the instant you move the cursor after clicking the image (i.e. it's scaled), the image jumps because its container which is the context for the x/y coordinates has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution might be to update the coordinates after the image get scaled (in the `click` callback after the `toggleClass`) in the same way as the `move` handler.

Like this:

```js
$('.zoom').click(function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('zoomed');
  move(e, $(this));
});

$('.zoom')
  .on('mousemove', function(e) {
    move(e, $(this));
  })

function move(e, elm) {
  elm.children('.zoom img').css({
    'transform-origin': ((e.pageX - elm.offset().left) / elm.width()) * 100 + '% ' + ((e.pageY - elm.offset().top) / $(this).height()) * 100 + '%'
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/moshfeu/8mcu23tn/

Comment: Hey that **does** fix the coordinates! I forked my Fiddle with your update and also changed my image to show an actual UX diagram to demonstrate something... For example, depending on where I click, let's say the first step in the flow (top left "Launch App"), the image scales/positions far to the left. Same behavior relative to clicking near the bottom, right, etc... I think I know why this is — but is it possible for the image to be positioned near the point of click when it scales? Forked Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iraishere/jxteo0r4/4/

Comment: To clarify, ideally whatever point in the image is clicked, would be in view upon scale.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you mac could do this but the container of the image (Let's say `.gallery-item-wrap` should be in the same size in both of the cases) I mean, that for example, the bottom left corner should be at the same coordinates on the screen when the image is in regular size and the bigger size. You understand what I mean?

Comment: — I wouldn't be able to change `.gallery-item-wrap` as there are multiple on the page, inline in the doc flow. While not totally perfect positioning around the perimeter, your edit to update the coordinates is working and solved the underlying problem so I will mark that as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: It's not a problem. By change I mean that the "frame" will not resize as it does now but remain the same, only the image will get the zoom. Exactly like this one: https://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/